# React - Canvas rendering, seperate draw logic & input logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

Sorry if this has been asked before i did search and couldn't find anything.

I am currently in the process of creating a react application and need to render details to a canvas. The program itself is going to be a map creation program. Currently I'm drawing to the canvas with the canvas context, although I want to change this out to konva or ocanvas eventually.

My isssue at the moment is I'm struggling to find a nice way to seperate everything as the canvas need to handle lots of mouse events, rendering the data, and "tool" selection and some data manupulation. Ideally I'd like to seperate this code out to a seperate units so all of the code isn't in one place. IE: rendering logic, input logic, etc...  How would I go about doing this? bearing in mind the map MAY need to be passed into the sub unit.

Below is a snippet of the code i currently have i have removed some of the granular details but have kept all my mouse code and values:

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  Fragment
} from "react";
import {
  useCanvas
} from './canvashooks/CanvasHooks.js';

const Canvas = ({map}) => {

  //far to many variables, is there a better way of doing this?
  const [offX, setOffX] = useState(0);
  const [offY, setOffY] = useState(0);
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1.0);
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);
  const [mouseUp, setMouseUp] = useState(false);
  const [initialX, setInitialX] = useState(0);
  const [initialY, setInitialY] = useState(0);
  const [offXStart, setOffXStart] = useState(0);
  const [offYStart, setOffYStart] = useState(0);


  const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);

  const draw = ctx => {
    console.log(map)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.clientWidth, ctx.canvas.clientHeight)

    //draw the buildings:
    if (map.Buildings === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    //draw data from the map
  }
  useEffect(() => {

    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    draw(context)
  }, [draw])

  const handleCanvasClick = (event) => {

  }

  const handleCanvasMouseDown = (event) => {
    let initialX = event.pageX;
    let initialY = event.pageY;
    setMouseDown(true);
    setInitialX(initialX);
    setInitialY(initialY);
    setOffXStart(offX);
    setOffYStart(offY);
  }

  const handleCanvasMouseUp = (event) => {
    console.log('Canvas Mouse Up');
    setMouseDown(false);
  }

  const handleCanvasDrag = (event) => {
    if (!mouseDown) {
      return;
    }
    let diffX = event.pageX - initialX;
    let diffY = event.pageY - initialY;

    let offX = offXStart + diffX;
    let offY = offXStart + diffY;
    setOffX(offX);
    setOffY(offY);
  }

  const handleCanvasMouseWheel = (event) => {
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
      setScale(scale + 0.1)
    }

    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      setScale(scale - 0.1)
    }
  }



  return ( 
    <div class = "box canvasContainer" >
    <canvas id = "renderCanvas"ref = {canvasRef} width = "1000" height = "1000" 
    onWheel = {handleCanvasMouseWheel} 
    onMouseMove = {handleCanvasDrag}
    onMouseUp = {handleCanvasMouseUp}
    onMouseDown = {handleCanvasMouseDown} 
    onClick = {handleCanvasClick}> Your browser doesnt support the canvas < /canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Canvas;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some considerations and thinking about the problem i have come up with the following solution:

Within the canvas class create and initlise a list of "tools" part of this inilisation is giving a list of callback functions to update the state IE: render scale & offsets. the within the event functions for the canvas call the event within the selected tool.

This method is quite expandable as any functions can be added to the callback, this means the tools can be coded to do anything. I also added a render function to the tool which get's called last and can render custom elements to the screen depending on the tool.